# Finding the euclidean coordinates of 4 dimensional line segments wrapped onto a 4-sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have a set of line-segments in 4 dimensions

$$
A = (-1,-1,-1,-1) \\
B = (0,0,0,0) \\
C = (1,1,1,1) \\
D = (-1,0,0,0) \\
... \\
\overline{AD}
$$

But I want to consider these points as coming from a cycle, where $2$ is actually equal to $-1$, and $-2$ is equal to $1$. In order to represent this, I am thinking of these points as being on the surface of a unit 4-sphere.

Is there a simple way to calculate the 5-dimensional coordinates of each point (this alone would be hugely helpful)? How about the curve that the line segment becomes on the surface of the 4-sphere?

As an illustration here is a picture of the problem in two dimensions.

[image]

Comment: Why the sphere? To make $\pm 2=\pm 1$, shift and work in $\Bbb RP^4$?

Comment: Can you explain that a bit more? In the two dimensional example, I was imagining physically rolling that shape up into a tube so that the -1,-1 overlap (which of course is a cylinder, I would also be fine with that for the 4 dimensional case). I haven't worked with anything in >3 dimensions before so I'm having a hard time even formulating the problem I guess.

Comment: When we identify the points $\pm x$ on the unit sphere, we obtain projective space. That’s why I said you should shift so that $-2$ and $1$ become symmetric with respect to the origin. I haven’t tried to think further about the details here.